# Storing NULLABLE columns in the end of table-Oracle

Tags: oracle

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CHDJHGEF) link states that all columns that are nullable should be added to the end of a database table to conserve space.

My question is how can I ensure that a column in always added to the end of database table. I am **assuming** that when I `CREATE TABLE ..`, I should add all NULLABLE columns in the end. But how does this work when I use `ALTER TABLE X ADD COLUMN ..`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle, unlike some DBMSes, offers no way to add a column at a specific position in the table; new columns are always added at the end. So, you can't do anything special for this. All you've got is:

- Usually, if your table has nullable columns, you won't be needing to add any new non-nullable columns (especially since you'd have to update all existing records to supply some sort of filler value).
- It's not *very* harmful to have nullable columns in the middle; all that means is that the length (0) needs to be stored when it otherwise would not. Unless you really have huge numbers of rows that have very little non-null data but lots of trailing nulls, this really won't make a significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation doesn't say that all trailing *nullable* columns don't take up any space. It says *"for trailing **null** columns, Oracle Database does not even store the column length."* - my emphasis. This means that for every column *without any data in it* Oracle does not store the *length* of the column.

The preceding sentence it reads *"To conserve space, a null in a column only stores the column length (zero)"*, i.e. Oracle only stores one byte per row for every null.

Thus, you won't save any space as soon as you add any data into the column. Also, even if your table is around 1m rows you'll only save 1MB, hardly anything. It's not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work if you use ALTER TABLE. If you absolutely need to re-arrange the table after changing it, you could use a create table as select (CTAS) to copy the data to another table (having the columns in the right order), drop your original table and rename your new table to the original table name afterwards.
Of course, dropping the original table would invalidate all other objects depending on your table, so this is probably not a viable option.